# Вместо отрытия страницы браузер скачивает файл *.shtml

Tags: html, веб-программирование, .htaccess

С недавнего времени сайт построенный на shtml страницах перестал их открывать, вместо этого он скачивает сам файл страницы, в .htaccess была запись:

```
<Files *.shtml>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
<Files *.html>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Если убрать эту запись то сайт начинает работать нормально, открывать страницы корректно, но перестают работать рекламные блоки, скрин:

[image: 1]

Поддержка хоста открещивается, говорит, смотрите в свой .htaccess, так же пробовал добавить запись

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .shtml
```

в .htaccess , но с этой записью снова начинает скачиваться файл вместо открытия страницы в браузере

Что делать, куда смотреть не пойму, или как точнее сказать хосту что у них не так? Потому что сайт работал лет 10 до января этого года с таким htaccess на shtml, т.е. с записью что выше показана, а в один день просто перестал, хотя ничего не меняли, хостинг использует панель plesk, если это о чем-то говорит

UPD: рекламный блок если я правильно понимаю вызывается через php внутри shtml файла:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_lxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx77/class.linkmoney.php');
echo $lm->getLinks(3);
?>
```